# SQL Server Management Studio 18 log files?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My SQL Server Management Studio 18.0 suddenly stopped working, it's not starting anymore. I couldn't find any logs in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18` and Google always tell me how to analyze logs of the SQL Server though I need the logs of the Management Studio. How can I analyze the startup problems of the SQL Server Management Studio? Where are the logs for that or how can they be enabled? 
Note: I already tried with reinstalling - didn't help.

Comment: Most likely: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37502512-ssms2018-installed-but-will-not-run

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Exactly, that's what I figured out after googling the log messages.  Sad this error is still included in the current downloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run SSMS with the `-log` parameter and see the error as

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" -log D:\log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Hints for others: using .xml extension and opening in Internet Explorer gives a nicer view than the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are experiencing is most likely [SSMS2018 - Installed, but will not run](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37502512-ssms2018-installed-but-will-not-run)

> The recommended workaround, in the interim, is:
>
> 1) Close all instances of SSMS
>
> 2) Edit ssms.exe.config
>
> 3) Remove the line that has the  following text (should be line 38):
>
> ```
> NgenBind_OptimizeNonGac  enabled=“1”
> ```
>
> That’s the same change that will be in the next release of SSMS 18.x